# Derivation of the effect of the Hadamard transform on a state |x⟩ in the Deutsch–Jozsa algorithm

Tags: quantum-algorithms, nielsen-and-chuang, hadamard, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

On pg. 35 of Nielsen and Chuang, there's the following paragraph:

> By checking the cases $x=0$ and $x=1$ separately we see that for a single qubit $H|x\rangle=\sum_x (-1)^{xz}|z\rangle/\sqrt{2}$.

I'm especially confused about its parts that involve $z$, such as why the power is $xz$ and what's the difference between $x$ and $z$. I can understand that the reason the denominator is $\sqrt{2}$ is due to $n=1$ in the summation part of the following formula:
$$
|\psi_2\rangle=\sum_x \frac{(-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle}{\sqrt{2^n}}\left[\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right]
$$

Comment: x is the input state index and z is the output state index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR: These formulas have nothing to do with each other. The first one is the definition of the Hadamard gate, the other one the state we're left with after having applied $f$. In the latter, the $z$ comes from the application of the Hadamard gate.

---

These formulas are not linked. The first one simply describes that, for a single qubit state $|x\rangle$, we have:
$$H|x\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle + (-1)^x|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}.$$
Indeed, we know that:
$$H|0\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle + |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$
and:
$$H|1\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle - |1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Thus we can write:
$$H|x\rangle=\frac{|0\rangle + (-1)^x|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[(-1)^{x\cdot 0}|0\rangle+(-1)^{x\cdot 1}|1\rangle\right]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_z(-1)^{x\cdot z}|z\rangle.$$
Note that this formula is *always* true, it is not specific to the Deutch-Josza algorithm, but is a property/definition of the Hadamard gate.

The second formula describes the state just after we've applied the function $f$ to the state:
$$\left|\psi_2\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_x(-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle\left[\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right]$$

What we want to do now is to apply an Hadamard gate on the first register. In order to do this, we can use the definition of the multi-qubit Hadamard gate which is given in the following paragraph and which can be seen as a generalization of the Hadamard gate for more than one qubit:
$$H|x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{z}(-1)^{x\cdot z}|z\rangle$$
This is where $z$ comes from: from the application of the Hadamard gate. Using this definition, we can now compute $\left|\psi_3\right\rangle$ by linearity:
$$\left|\psi_3\right\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_x(-1)^{f(x)}H|x\rangle\left[\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right]$$
which is, according to the formula of $H|x\rangle$:
$$\left|\psi_3\right\rangle=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_x(-1)^{f(x)}\sum_z(-1)^{x\cdot z}|z\rangle\left[\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right]$$
which is also equal to:
$$\left|\psi_3\right\rangle=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_z\sum_x(-1)^{x\cdot z+f(x)}|z\rangle\left[\frac{|0\rangle-|1\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\right]$$
which is the state described by Nielsen and Chuang in equation (1.51).